# Agregar palabras a un array

Tags: javascript, html, array

Hola estoy trabajando con diferentes archivos html, mi intención es desde un html (nombre de ejemplo: html numero 2) agregue palabras mayúsculas al array ubicado en el primer archivo js. Es para un juego. Sin embargo no logro añadir las palabras y el juego solo trabaja con las palabras incluidas en el array original.

```js
let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];


function agregarPalabra(){

    let agrego = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();

    palabras.push(agrego);

}
```

```html
   //Segundo archivo html, invoco la función del primer archivo js
    <input type='text' id="texto">
   
    <input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Guardar Palabra'onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>
```

---

Según los comentarios el código funciona correctamente pero en mi caso no se agregan las palabras, amplio un poco más el código por si hay algo que este mal:

```js
//Primer archivo JS (primer.js)


//Función para reemplazar el caracter por la letra
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) { return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length); }

let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];

let palabra = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random()*palabras.length)];

//Reemplazo la palabra por guiones
let palabraConGuiones = palabra.replace(/./g, "_ ");

let contadorFallos = 7;

document.querySelector('#salida00').innerHTML = palabraConGuiones;

document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){

    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()

});

document.querySelector('#boton00').addEventListener('click',function(){


function agregarLetra(){

    let elementoLetra = document.createElement('span');

    elementoLetra.innerHTML = letra.toUpperCase();

    letrasUsadas.appendChild(elementoLetra);

}

let letra = document.querySelector('#letra00').value.toUpperCase();

let haFallado = true;

for(var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++){
        
        if(letra == palabra[i]){
            
            //i*2 se debe a que la letra es reemplazada por 2 caracteres; un guión y un espacio.
            palabraConGuiones = palabraConGuiones.replaceAt(i*2, letra);
            
            haFallado = false;

          

        }
    }

if(haFallado){
    
        contadorFallos--;

        if(contadorFallos >= 0 && contadorFallos <= 7){
            document.getElementById('vida').innerHTML = 'El numero de vidas que te quedan son: ' + contadorFallos;
        //document.querySelector('#ahorcado00').style.backgroundPosition = -(173*contadorFallos) + 'px 0';
        }
        
        if(contadorFallos == 0){
            
            document.querySelector('#dead').style.display = 'inline-block';
        
        }
        }else{
            if(palabraConGuiones.indexOf('_') <0){

                document.querySelector('#parca-triste').style.display = 'inline-block';
            
            }
     
    }

   dibujar();

   limpiar();
    
   agregarLetra(letra);

});

function agregarPalabra(){

    let agrego = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();

    palabras.push(agrego);

}
```

```html
 // html esta conectado a los 2 archivos js
 
 <input type='text' id="texto">
    
    <input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Guardar Palabra'onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>

    <input type='button' id="mostrar-palabra" value = 'Mostrar palabras' onclick= 'mostrarPalabra()'>

      <script src='primer.js'></script>
  
      <script src="segundo.js"></script>
```

```js
// Segundo archivo JS (segundo.js)

document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

});

let datos = [];

function mostrarPalabra(){

    let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    resultado.innerHTML = '';

    for(let dato of datos){

        let datoParrafo = document.createElement('p');

        datoParrafo.innerText = dato;

        resultado.appendChild(datoParrafo);

    }

}
```

Comment: Tu código funciona, si escribes algo en el `input` se agrega. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Entonces el problema debe estar en otra parte del código, voy a tener que fijarme mejor, cualquier cosa agrego más línea de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza localStorage, así podrás guardar localmente los datos que ingreses en el arreglo.

```
  let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];
  palabras=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("palabras"));//Carga el arreglo json a objeto.
  function agregarPalabra(){
    let agrego = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();
    palabras.push(agrego);
    localStorage.setItem('palabras',JSON.stringify(palabras));//Guarda el arreglo en formato JSON.
  }
```

Esto solo funciona localmente, podrías implementar firebase o algún pequeño servidor web ya sea php/[Express.js](https://expressjs.com/es/starter/hello-world.html) para almacenar las palabras y puedas acceder donde sea.